# php 301 redirects actually doing a 302 redirect

Tags: php, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have been googling for this but no one appears to have the answer.

This post describes the problem well:

http://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg198576.html

Server is Windows 2008
FastCGI
PHP 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only answer to this one at the moment is to not use FastCGI on IIS7 when using PHP (because of a bug in FastCGI) - which is rubbish because it's very quick.  Using isapi allows the 301 redirects to work as they should, but it's not as fast.

Answer (score 1):

microsoft released a fix for this:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=980363&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PHP here to test this, but wouldn't this produce a 301?

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 301);
```

Comment: You would think so but no, it produces a 302 redirect

Comment: I would be tempted to delete this answer, but I think it'd be better to leave it here so someone else doesn't suggest the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It *should* be as given by R. Bemrose; that's the usual example code. I guess there is something not-quite-right about your PHP execution environment.

Another method you can try is the CGI standard way of passing back a status line:

```
header('Status: 301 Moved permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: That should work, and I would expect it to, but it's just not.  I read that it might be a bug in the FastCGI module, but I can't find anything to fix it.