# PHP 301 Redirect, Impossible?

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

I have been trying to do a proper 301 redirect and have failed to do so.  No matter what i try, its always a 302 redirect.

Returns a 302:

```
http_redirect("urlgoeshere", '', false, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM)
```

Returns a 302:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: urlgoeshere");
```

Can anyone explain why these are coming back as 302's and not 301's?  Server OS is linux, running PHP/5.2.14.  Try it yourself.

I will give you guys a URL to try.  I am testing using YSlow and Googlebot.

Should be 301: http://www.fantasysp.com/player/mlb/Albert_Pujols/1486349

[image: Firebug shows a 302 Code]

Comment: Works for me: `$ curl http://localhost/test.php -i` → `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` We need more information about your environment.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, or Mac? Apparently IIS has some issues...

Comment: possible duplicate of [php 301 redirects actually doing a 302 redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562243/php-301-redirects-actually-doing-a-302-redirect)

Comment: Make sure you're not overlooking something simple, like editing the wrong file, uploading to the wrong server, etc...

Comment: Server is running in Linux, so its not exactly a dupe of the other article, which refers to IIS.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pretty straightforward actually:

```
header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);
```

[image]

---

If you're using FastCGI try doing this instead:

```
header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', true);
header('Location: ' . $url); // or header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work.  I added the URL to a live page that shows 302 for me.  Do you see 302 as well?

Comment: @brant: I see 301. What are you using to check the HTTP response code?

Comment: Interesting. I am testing using YSlow in Firefox and looking at Googlebot's response in Webmaster Tools.  Both show 302 for me.

Comment: @brant: I don't know how to see that in YSlow but I've posted a screenshot of the code and HTTP response as FireBug sees it. What web server are you using?

Comment: @brant: Are you running PHP as CGI or as an Apache module?

Comment: @Alix I'm running Apache/2.2.15 with PHP/5.2.14.

Comment: @brant: What is the output of `var_dump(php_sapi_name());`?

Comment: @Alix, that question I am unsure of. However, according to the output of phpinfo(), it says: "GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1" under the "PHP Variables" section.

Comment: @Alix string(14) "apache2handler"

Comment: @brant: Ok, that's weird indeed. Try the new snippet I provided and refer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562243/php-301-redirects-actually-doing-a-302-redirect for other possible solutions. I'm out of ideas, maybe ServerFault.com or submitting a PHP Bug would be better places to seek help. Sorry! =\

Comment: @ Alix, you still rock for sticking with me this far.  I truly appreciate your help. If I get no responses tomorrow, then I'll just select your answer as accepted answer.  

For now I am sticking a canonical link in the header to help Google select the right URL to index.