# How to make a 301 redirect from PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

`example.com/video.php` – this link should redirect to `example.com/videos/`.

I’ve tried but it isn’t working. I want 301 redirect.

This is my code in `video.php`:

```
<?php
// 301 redirect from php
header('Location: /videos/');
?>
```

I want the full code for doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 301 Redirect, Impossible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268454/php-301-redirect-impossible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.example.com/videos"); 
?>
```

The `http://` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with PHP 5.4 you can simplify code output with the [http_response_code()](https://www.php.net/http-response-code) function:

```
<?php
    http_response_code(301);
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/videos");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use this single line:

```
<?php 
header("Location: http://www.example.org/videos", TRUE, 301); exit();
?>
```

Remember to add  `exit()` or `die()` at the end.